# Validate a value in sql using and if exists statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, validating

I am still pretty new to everything and now I am trying to validate my input SQL.

My powershell script allows me to se some variables which I want to enter in a selected database. What I need is a check if the entry already exists or not. And if it exists my script shall stop.

Script part :

```
if exists(select * from [DB1].dbo.[table1]
            where Name = '$variable1')

    "stop script but how?"

else

    insert into ......
```

So I need something which replaces "stop script but how?" somehow :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you need to "stop" the script? Reverse your logic - if the thing *doesn't* exist, only *then* do the rest of the stuff.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...)
BEGIN
    -- do all the things
END
```

Comment: [I'd prefer a prize, I think](http://www.biography.com/imported/images/Biography/Images/Profiles/P/Vincent-Price-9446990-1-402.jpg), but thanks. :-) Credit to @JNK for the image.